# Create slice mask in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, slice

Is there a way to specify a mask based on a slice operation?
For example

```
A = torch.arange(6).view((2,3))
# A = [[0,1,2], [3,4,5]]

mask_slice = torch.mask_slice(A[:,1:])
# mask_slice = [[0,1,1],[0,1,1]]
```

Comment: your question is not clear. How do you want to define the mask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (if I got your question right):

```
mask_slice = torch.zeros(A.shape, dtype=bool)
mask_slice[:, 1:] = 1

# tensor([[False,  True,  True],
#         [False,  True,  True]])
```